# IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 8

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, if-statement

I would like to delete a Numpy Array element in a for loop if it exceedes my limits. If an element is out of limits and the numpy delete function deletes it, the end of the range of my for loop, n, decreases by 1. but inside the for loop it doesn't decrease and I get the following error. How can I remove elements from numpy array without breaking my for loop?

IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 8

```
n=9
ucl=0 + (3 * 1/ np.sqrt(n))
lcl=0 - (3 * 1/ np.sqrt(n))
x=np.random.normal(0,1,size=n)
for i in range(0,n):
  if (xbar[i]>ucl) | (xbar[i]<lcl):
    xbar=np.delete(xbar, i)
    n=n-1
```

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example? The identifier `xbar` is undefined. Also, the recommended operator for Boolean reasoning is `or`. Another recommendation is to follow [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), for example by surrounding the assignment symbol `=` with a single space on each side, and using 4 spaces of indentation per level of indentation.

Comment: The `range(0,n)` iteration is fixed by the initial `n`.  And with the `delete`, `xbar` size is changing.  Also `delete` makes a whole new array each time, so this is inefficient. Removing items from a list iterative is more efficient, but even there you have to be very careful about the iteration count and order.  In fact, we usually delete from the end to avoid messing up the indexing.

Comment: `np.delete` lets you specify  a list or array of indices to delete.  So you should be able to do this with just one `np.delete` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your n=n-1 instruction isn't indented correctly.
Your solution must be:

```
for i in range(0,n):
    if (xbar[i]>ucl) | (xbar[i]<lcl):
        xbar=np.delete(xbar, i)
n=n-1
```

Comment: I made a silly mistake. Thank you for your help.